# python and celery: override hard timeouts for use with gevent pool

Tags: python, class, error-handling, overriding, celery

Is there a way to override hard timeouts in celery? I know that I can do this with task inheritance for failed jobs.

```
class MyTask(Task):
def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
    print('{0!r} failed: {1!r}'.format(task_id, exc))

@app.task(base=MyTask, soft_time_limit=5, time_limit=10)
def add(x, y):
    raise KeyError()
```

But a hard timeout is not a failed job. The reason why I want to do this is because soft timeouts do not work with the gevent pool, only hard timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a bit to figure out, but this is how you do it. inherit from Request and then inherit from Task. Call to Request (where the on_failure method resides) from MyTask.

```
class MyRequest(Request):
    def on_timeout(self, soft, timeout):
        super(MyRequest, self).on_timeout(soft, timeout)
        if not soft:
           logger.warning(
               'A hard timeout was enforced for task %s',
               self.task.name
           )


class MyTask(Task):
    Request = MyRequest  # you can use a FQN 'my.package:MyRequest'

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print('{0!r} failed: {1!r}'.format(task_id, exc))


def run_time_job():
    a = random.randrange(0, 20)
    print('sleeping for', a)
    time.sleep(a)


@app.task(base=MyTask, soft_time_limit=5, time_limit=10)
def add(x, y):
    results = None
    try:
        run_time_job()
        results = x + y
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        print('time limit exceeded')
        redis_db.sadd('failed_jobs', 'failed at {} + {}'.format(x, y))
    except TimeLimitExceeded:
        raise KeyError()
    return results
```